# how to monitor android adb logcat and do a grep?

Tags: android, bash, adb

I have an application that can print some logs into android log system, it has some keywords that I want to monitor, what I want to achieve is:

Monitor "adb logcat" output, if there is a new line contains the keyword, print out the new line.

It's something like adb logcat | grep "command" but as you know adb logcat will block there so  my grep can't see any input. Is it doable using simple shell script?

Comment: adb logcat | grep "Web Console" #worksforme

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html, in the section titled **Filtering Log Output**, this describes `adb`'s native filtering capabilities. This will probably work for you. You can specify a specific tag in your log statements (which would essentially be whatever you would have sent to `bash`) and then just filter on those tags. For example:

```
android.util.Log.v("filter1","<this is my log statement>");
```

would be the code, and you'd then do

```
adb logcat filter1:V
```

to filter for that output.

EDIT: you can always use this to dump to a file, and then run `bash` on that.

Comment: Thanks, but looks like not ideal enough. Can I clear the log each time I dumped to a file? Otherwise the same line may be processed multiple times...

Comment: You can run `adb logcat -c` to flush the log in between runs. Also, you can run `adb logcat -d` to dump the log to screen and exit immediately, which may be what you need to feed it into `bash`.

Comment: Right. And today I found one conclusion about the orders of options. That is, if I use this cmd: `adb logcat -s -v time MYTAG -d`, it doesn't dump and exit. The right order is: `adb logcat -d -s -v time MYTAG`.

Answer (score 3):

To view logcat for a particular process :

```
 adb logcat | grep <process_id>
```

To view logcat for a particular process with the tag name too :

```
 adb logcat | grep <process_id> | grep -s "TAG NAME"
```

`|` acts as a separator for combining different queries.

Answer (score 0):

you can try in following manner

```
log_1=$(adb shell dumpsys meminfo com.azoi.azoitv | grep Views:) 
echo $log_1
```

if you want to perform in continuous loop, u can try this:

```
while :
do
    log_1=$(adb shell dumpsys meminfo com.azoi.azoitv | grep Views:)
    echo  $log_1
done
```